# Exposing the K8s API Server service using DNAT

Tags: kubernetes

I want to forward the control plane service through NAT.

```
                      ------------------                                      ------------------
                      |     nat        |                                      | kube-apiserver |
--- 10.0.0.1:30000 ---|-eno1    enp2s0-|-192.168.0.254/24----192.168.0.1:6443-|                |
                      |                |                                      |                |
                      ------------------                                      ------------------
```

What should I do?

I issue the following command in nat

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eno1--dport 30000 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.1:6443
```

Use the following command on nat to get a reply

```
curl -k https://192.168.0.1:6443/livez?verbose

[+]ping ok
[+]log ok
[+]etcd ok
[+]poststarthook/start-kube-apiserver-admission-initializer ok
[+]poststarthook/generic-apiserver-start-informers ok
[+]poststarthook/start-apiextensions-informers ok
[+]poststarthook/start-apiextensions-controllers ok
[+]poststarthook/crd-informer-synced ok
[+]poststarthook/bootstrap-controller ok
[+]poststarthook/rbac/bootstrap-roles ok
[+]poststarthook/scheduling/bootstrap-system-priority-classes ok
[+]poststarthook/start-cluster-authentication-info-controller ok
[+]poststarthook/start-kube-aggregator-informers ok
[+]poststarthook/apiservice-registration-controller ok
[+]poststarthook/apiservice-status-available-controller ok
[+]poststarthook/kube-apiserver-autoregistration ok
[+]autoregister-completion ok
[+]poststarthook/apiservice-openapi-controller ok
healthz check passed
```

Use the following command on nat can`t get a reply

```
curl -k https://10.0.0.1:30000/livez?verbose
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.0.0.1 port 30000: Connection refused
```